# Doing exact search across multiple fields

Tags: python, algorithm, search

Let's say I have the search term:

```
"Terminator 2 US" (search terms can be in any order)
```

And my data is as follows:

```
movie                   country     year
Terminator 2            US          1990
Avatar                  CA          2000
Terminator 2            GB          1990
2001: A Space Odyssey   US          1980
```

The result I should get is only the first row, based on an exact match on `movie=Terminator 2` and and exact match on `country=US`.

However, if I were to break everything up by terms and compare each of those based on exact value. I would get the following:

```
terminator ==> miss
2 ==> miss
us ==> match
```

Does this mean to do a search, I would need to create the following three search patterns to check against:

```
MATCH "terminator" AND MATCH "2" AND MATCH "US"
OR
MATCH "terminator 2" AND MATCH "US"
OR
MATCH "terminator 2 US"
```

Or, what would be the best way to do this sort of multi-field search? What if, for example, I have a 100 words in the search term? For example, is this a common pattern in search or what might I be missing?

```
for row in row:
    if  (row['movie'] == "Terminator 2 US") \
  or (row['movie'] == "Terminator 2") and row['country'] == 'US' \
  or (row['movie'] == "Terminator") and row['country'] == '2 US' \
  or (row['movie'] == "US") and row['country'] == 'Terminator 2' \
  or (row['movie'] == "Terminator 2") and row['year'] == 'US' \
  or (row['movie'] == "Terminator") and row['year'] == '2 US' \
  or (row['movie'] == "US") and row['year'] == 'Terminator 2' \
  # etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to provide a decent, relevancy based search, I strongly suggest looking at existing, dedicated technologies that provide that - such as [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) and [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (both based on [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/), so they're similar in what features they provide in relation to the actual search). These will give you a toolkit that allow you to configure and tune how your fields and relevancy scores will be processed.

A common way to solve the problem you're having is to copy everything into a common field so you only match against that, or query each field for each token separately. I'll give you an example using the latter, and attempt to relate the implementation to what the same concept in Lucene would be.

I'll use the term "tokenize" which means how a text is broken into separate pieces. These tokens are then matches against each other to see if the field contains a hit. In this example a whitespace tokenizer would work fine, which breaks the input into separate tokens on white space (' '). There are other tokenizers available that behaves differently, such as also splitting on `:` - which would be relevant for your fourth document if you want to be able to get a hit if the user searches for `2001`.

The example below is a brute force approach, in reality you'll have to maintain a proper, sorted index (and an inverted index) with all the content (tokens) present as the number of documents grow and you still want efficient search and scoring (which allow you to say that a hit in `title` is more important than in `year`, etc.).

```
data = [
{
    'title': 'Terminator 2',
    'country': 'US',
    'year': '1990',
}, {
    'title': 'Avatar',
    'country': 'CA',
    'year': '2000',
}, {
    'title': 'Terminator 2',
    'country': 'GB',
    'year': '1990',
}, {
    'title': '2001: A Space Odyssey',
    'country': 'US',
    'year': '1980',
}]

query = 'Terminator 2 US'

def match_token_for_document(token, document):
    # any splitting and filtering (lower()) would only be performed
    # when a document is indexed in a proper solution, not for each
    # query
    for field in doc:
        for doc_token in doc[field].split():
            # A lowercase filter in a proper document search engine
            if doc_token.lower() == token:
                return True

    return False

for doc in data:
    hits = True

    # This would be a whitespace tokenizer in ES/Solr
    for token in query.split():
        if not match_token_for_document(token.lower(), doc):
            hits = False
            break

    if hits:
        print("Match:")
        print(doc)
```

The output is the Terminator 2 (US):

```
Match:
{'country': 'US', 'year': '1990', 'title': 'Terminator 2'}
```

Comment: thanks for this explanation and example. All the technology for this needs to be in the browser -- either in javascript or c++ (webassembly) so we're not really able to use external products (I don't think). Even if the search would be 1000x faster -- the network of transferring 10k documents would make it even slower (all rows show like Excel, not paginated to a small chunk of results). Given this, what approach would you suggest?

Comment: also, for now Scoring/sorting doesn't matter, just whether it's a match or not.

Comment: As long as searches are done rather seldom, an iterating solution would work fine. Depending on the size of the rows, adding an already tokenized and lowercased version as a common column would probably be a good idea; it wouldn't require much processing when new values rows are created or when a document is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the query and the row values to sets and check if they match, or if the query set is sub set of the values in case of partial query

```
q = 'Terminator 2 US'
# or
q = 'Terminator 2 US 1990'
# or
q = 'Terminator 2 1990 US'

for row in rows:
    row_values = ' '.join(row.values())
    values_set = set(row_values.split(' '))
    query_set = set(q.split(' '))
    if values_set == query_set or values_set.issuperset(query_set):
        matches.append(row)
```

Comment: yes that's a trivial example above. I mean imagine there are lots of fields and it won't always be in that order. I can update the question.

Comment: thanks. What would 'rows' be in this example. Is this a list of dicts?

Comment: is the performance of this solution roughly the same as the above one? Just curious what the differences might be.